# Authentication with mod_python without login credentials popup

Tags: apache, mod-python

I am using Centos server with apache server.
I have added python script that reads my website's login cookie and based on that it return apache.OK or apache.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED. 
However even if cookies is present, it will pop up that login form.

Any help on how to remove that pop up is appreciated.

I tried removing AuthType Basic, but than i get following error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

```
  <Directory "/var/www/html/reports" >
  AddHandler mod_python .py
  PythonHandler /tmp/access.py
  PythonAuthenHandler /tmp/access.py
  PythonDebug On
  SSLRequireSSL
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  #AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Area"
  AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
  Options -Indexes
  require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

just found out if you don't want login pop up , you will have to set up req.user to something

It was throwing error before that req.user  is null.
I did this `req.user = "nobody"`